# How to deploy an old build

Tags: bamboo

I accidentally deleted a deployment project and lost all the deployment history and releases.

I manually recreated the deployment project and environments. I already created a release from the latest build and deployed it to one of the environments, now I want to deploy an old build to one of the other environments.

When I try to create the release however I get the error "Build 611 cannot be used as it has to be built after the 621 linked to release build-621-deploy-542"
How do I create a release with Build 611 in?

I assume I need to rebuild build 611 when I go to build 611 there is a Rebuild option. However is that going to rebuild the same commit from git or is it going to use the latest version in git?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy with old version, you have an option to choose it. After clicking the deploy icon, there you will get an option of choosing the radio button "promote existing release to this environment", there you can choose the old build in dropdown. It will deploy the old artifact or release with features without the recent commit, these details will be shown in the right panel on the same page.

I hope rerun will checkout the original version of that build, and it wont take latest code. If you still want to be sure for old code, there you have option "Run customized build" to choose the specific revision of git or bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete all releases with a newer version. After that, you will be able to create the release which you want.